# Ping Pong Ball and Spinning Billard Ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

A student sent me a Tik Tok with saying it "Breaks Physics".  A person hits a ping pong ball to a billard ball.  The ball does not move.  The person spins the billard ball, then hits the ping pong ball and the ball goes into the pocket.  Why does this happen? I thought a spinning object required more force to move. (granted I teach Middle School)

Any thoughts about how this works?

Comment: Which Tik Tok, please?

Comment: @Gert That something people send can send eachother in private via an app. Maybe it's better to remove the part from the question because it's otherwise irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If the billiard ball does not move when struck by the ping pong ball, it means that the impulse from the ping pong ball was not sufficient to overcome the static friction between the billiard ball and the table.  If the billiard ball is spinning, the friction is kinetic and smaller.

Comment: In the spinning case, the point of the ball which is in contact with the ground is (theoretically) stationary, so why does kinetic friction act instead of static friction?

Comment: On a felt covered table, the area of contact is of finite size.

Comment: Yes. So, practically your explanation is completely sound. I was just wondering what if we talked on theoretically....